# Why not switch to NIST SHA3

Tags: hashing

Currently we use the draft sha3 standard which specified LFSR of 0x01, however NIST's approved SHA3 is set to 0x06. If we switched to using this hash method it would allow many more options of crypto libraries to be used. Surely the next major release of IRI could do this immediately following a snapshot without too much harm? Or perhaps a transition period could be implemented where both are supported for 30 days or something.

More info: 
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15727/what-are-the-key-differences-between-the-draft-sha-3-standard-and-the-keccak-sub